# Passing Arguments within If Statement

Tags: function, if-statement, arguments

I'm trying to pass arguments between two files, and am encountering issues. I'm trying to parse a message for the word 'foo' in it, and create a function that will check if the message is only 'foo' or perhaps is a word like 'foot', which contains foo but isn't the word foo. Here's the two files

```
test2.py

import os, sys
from functiontest import function

message = 'foo'
check = 0

if 'foo' in message:
    function(message,check)
    print(check)
    print('bar')
else:
    check = 0
if check == 0:
    print('foo not recognized')
```

and the function file

```
functiontest.py

import os, sys

def function(a,b):
    print('checking message')
    a = a.split()
    print(a)
    if a[0] == 'foo':
        b = 1
        print(b)
        return b
    else:
        b = 0
        return b
```

When run, it indicates that when b is set to 1 and passes it, it doesn't get passed correctly and remains 0. I want it to pass the argument check to be 1 if it is detected that the word isn't exactly 'foo' so that the message will appear saying that 'foo is not detected'. What am I doing wrong?

Follow up question: Once check is confirmed as 0 within the if statement, is there a way to break the statement and not execute the next lines that are within that if statement and rather skip to the else statement? I would prefer to include this somehow in the function to make the main code look cleaner,  because I could include more embedded if statements but I want to avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're throwing away the return value of `function`, then printing `check`, which was never changed from the original value of 0. I believe your intent was to reassign `check` with the return value of the function:

```
check = function(message,check)
print(check)
```

Comment: Ah, that was it! Thanks! I also forgot to include part of my question, I edited the post at the end to include it, if you have any insight that would be great.